# Android ProgressDialog thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, return-value, progressdialog

How to show ProgressDialog in separate UI thread?

I have the following code:

```
public boolean myMethod() {

  // show here ProgressDialog in thread

  // long operation, MUST BE NOT in thread, as there's a return value...

  return value;
}
```

Using Handler, Thread, AsyncTask didn't help...

Is there any way to run ProgressDialog in separate thread and main (long) operation in main thread?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm curious why AsyncTask didn't help? That is exactly what it's for. And it's really the other way around, the ProgressDialog will run on the main thread, and the long running operation will run on a separate non-main thread. AsyncTask has methods to pass the return value from the background thread back to the main thread -- should work?

Comment: It doesn't work, if long operation works in main thread, not in separate thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one UI thread. You should never run anything heavy in it. I'm afraid you have to run that in the background and the progress bar in the UI thread.

You might have to do a bit redesigning to achieve that. You can use callbacks to get rid of the return values.